# How to add my facebook webpage to an href link in wordpress header

Tags: php, wordpress, href, social-media

Working with a developer from india that got his money and stopped coding. I have the following code: and want to add www.facebook.com/"mypage"

```
href="<?php echo get_option('facebook');?>"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f
```

This is on wordpress. Does anyone know where in this code i can add the /mypage? currently the link goes to facebook so i know its coded somewhere but i cant find it.

I've tried to plug and chug but that didn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

`get_option()` is a Wordpress function sometimes used to code custom settings options into Wordpress' admin dashboard. I want to say the setting is accessible through the dashboard, though I couldn't say where exactly. The first place I'd look is in Settings > General/Reading/(some custom submenu item). If you don't come up with anything, check for any social media plugins taking a URL for a Facebook link.